# Unclear about Ruby gem installations

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

When you do `gem install someGem`, does it install it in your system so it's available for all your projects, or does it only install it for the project that's associated with the folder you're currently in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how it is set up. Normally it would be available for all projects but it can be set up as in this tutorial http://janveldeman.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/project-specific-rubygems/ (From 2008 so might require a big of playing to get working with newer versions) to be specific to individual projects.

Comment: Why is it that when install a gem that I already installed it always downloads it? Shouldn't it say that the gem is already installed?

Comment: Does it do this if you try and install twice on the same project?

Comment: If I run the same exact command like "gem install execjs" in the same directory two times I get the same exact output.

Comment: This is just how gems does things, it isn't an install in the same way as an application on your computer, hense why you can run the install on the same directory multiple times.

Comment: Where do gems get installed to. If I found a few in a hidden directory, but when I did "gem list" I found a lot.